# Deploying Pull Requests using Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops

I have two stages in my [release pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgUsC.png) in azure pipelines for pull request deployment: "PR" and "PR2". However, when there is a PR to master branch, build is deployed to both stages and when there is a new PR, it again deploys to both stages and overrides the existing PR deployment.

Is there a way to limit PR deployment to only one available stage and not overriding a stage where another PR is already deployed?

Answer (score 0):

A stage is a **logical** and **independent** entity that represents where you want to deploy a release generated from a release pipeline.

About the concept of stage, you could take a look at this official tutorial: [Release stages, queuing policies, and options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/environments?view=azure-devops)

When you set a pull request trigger in release, you can configure it that will create a new release when a pull request uploads a new version of the artifact.

Enable the trigger and add the branches targeted by pull requests that you want to activate this trigger.

However, even though a release is automatically created, it might not be deployed automatically to any stages. The **stage triggers** govern **when and if a release should be deployed to a stage.**

Actually not totally get your point.  If one branch corresponding  to a stage, you could use branch filter in release. If one pull request corresponding to a stage, how would you judge which pull request deploy which stage?

Comment: I want to have something similar to [Gitlab dynamic environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments.html#dynamic-environments) but looks like what I'm asking is a new feature request and not supported currently.

Branch filters require developer to select a particular branch name in order to target a PR stage. I was wondering if there was a smarter way to deploy a pull request to one of the stages allocated for PR deployments e.g. round robin.